# Ajax Jquery form function

Tags: jquery, ajax, function

I'm making some proves with jquery and I get something strange to me. 
for some reason this code doesn't work with the commented line but works just fine if I uncomment it. 
Can someone tellme why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function procesar() {
        //$('#destino').html('hola');
        $("#destino").load("HTML-1.html");
    };
</script>
<div id="destino"> 
     <form name="form" method="post" action='' onSubmit='procesar()' id="form">
          <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Enviar" class="box" id="boton" >
    </form>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain what "doesn't work" means in this case? (What do you expect to happen and what actually happens?)

Answer (score 0):

I would assume because the top line runs synchronously not allowing time for the event to finish before removing essentially overriding the event dispatcher. The second works because load fires asynchronously and allows the event to finish dispatching before overriding the dispatcher.